# Unpack C# struct into Python

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x, struct, unpack

I have a c# struct

```
public struct QData {
        public DateTime time_stamp;
        public decimal a;
        public decimal b;
        public decimal a_s;
        public decimal b_s;
    }
```

.NET DateTime type is 8 bytes, Decimal type is 16 bytes, so the overall size is 72 bytes

I want to get results of in Python and have started with the below, but given those are not standard C# types, I can't figure out how to unpack.

```
import mmap
import struct

tag_name = 'MyTagName'
shmem = mmap.mmap(0, 72, tag_name, mmap.ACCESS_READ)
print(shmem.readline())


s = struct.unpack('72B', shmem)
print(s)
```

This returns:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

From everything I've read I can't even tell if unpacking all as unsigned char is correct, let alone how I would go about converting the datetime and decimal fields.

Comment: Apologies if I'm not even wording correctly. I have decent experience in python, but no experience working in C# or with binary data.

Comment: You should simplify the code in your question as much as possible (i.e. make it a [mre]). For example using `mmap` has nothing whatsoever to do with what you want to know.

Comment: Why not serialise the data into json before putting into shared memory?  Then you won't have the marshalling problem.

Comment: The data is from a service the company runs for multiple consumers. I don’t have any control over the data production.

Comment: Why not access 'service' directly with python script?